# More than one @XmlID in JAXB generated class

Tags: java, xml, soap, jaxb, eclipselink

I am using **Netbeans 8.0.1** with JDK 1.7 to compile an xsd file to Java classes. The xsd includes as namespaces `xmlns:soapenv` and `xmlns:soapenc` so the compiler also generates the 
`org.xmlsoap.schemas.soap.encoding` and `org.xmlsoap.schemas.soap.envelope` packages.

The thing is, that inside `org.xmlsoap.schemas.soap.encoding` package the `ID.java` class that is
generated contains two `@XmlID` annotations and when I try to **unmarshal** I get:

> Exception Description: An attempt was made to set more than one XmlID
>   property on class [org.xmlsoap.schemas.soap.encoding.ID].  Property
>   [value] cannot be set as XmlID, because property [id] is already set
>   as XmlID.
>    - with linked exception: [Exception [EclipseLink-50030] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd):
>   org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JAXBException Exception
>   Description: An attempt was made to set more than one XmlID property
>   on class [org.xmlsoap.schemas.soap.encoding.ID].  Property [value]
>   cannot be set as XmlID, because property [id] is already set as
>   XmlID.]

As a workaround I removed the `@XmlID` annotation from the value property and the unmarshalling worked. Is that how I should proceed?

Here is the generated **ID.java** class:

```
//
// This file was generated by the JavaTM Architecture for XML Binding(JAXB) Reference Implementation, v2.2.5-2 
// See <a href="http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxb">http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxb</a> 
// Any modifications to this file will be lost upon recompilation of the source schema. 

package org.xmlsoap.schemas.soap.encoding;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAnyAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlID;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchemaType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlValue;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.CollapsedStringAdapter;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;


/**
 * <p>Java class for ID complex type.
 * 
 * <p>The following schema fragment specifies the expected content contained within this class.
 * 
 * <pre>
 * &lt;complexType name="ID">
 *   &lt;simpleContent>
 *     &lt;extension base="&lt;http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema>ID">
 *       &lt;attGroup ref="{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/}commonAttributes"/>
 *       &lt;anyAttribute processContents='lax' namespace='##other'/>
 *     &lt;/extension>
 *   &lt;/simpleContent>
 * &lt;/complexType>
 * </pre>
 * 
 * 
 */
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "ID", propOrder = {
    "value"
})
public class ID {

    @XmlValue
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(CollapsedStringAdapter.class)
    @XmlID
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "ID")
    protected java.lang.String value;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "id")
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(CollapsedStringAdapter.class)
    @XmlID
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "ID")
    protected java.lang.String id;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "href")
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "anyURI")
    protected java.lang.String href;
    @XmlAnyAttribute
    private Map<QName, java.lang.String> otherAttributes = new HashMap<QName, java.lang.String>();

    /**
     * Gets the value of the value property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link java.lang.String }
     *     
     */
    public java.lang.String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the value property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link java.lang.String }
     *     
     */
    public void setValue(java.lang.String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the id property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link java.lang.String }
     *     
     */
    public java.lang.String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the id property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link java.lang.String }
     *     
     */
    public void setId(java.lang.String value) {
        this.id = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the href property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link java.lang.String }
     *     
     */
    public java.lang.String getHref() {
        return href;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the href property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link java.lang.String }
     *     
     */
    public void setHref(java.lang.String value) {
        this.href = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets a map that contains attributes that aren't bound to any typed property on this class.
     * 
     * <p>
     * the map is keyed by the name of the attribute and 
     * the value is the string value of the attribute.
     * 
     * the map returned by this method is live, and you can add new attribute
     * by updating the map directly. Because of this design, there's no setter.
     * 
     * 
     * @return
     *     always non-null
     */
    public Map<QName, java.lang.String> getOtherAttributes() {
        return otherAttributes;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE - stripped down version of the xml schema**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
    xmlns:tns="urn:me-org:custom-3-1"
    targetNamespace="urn:me-org:custom-3-1"
    elementFormDefault="unqualified"
    attributeFormDefault="unqualified">

    <xs:import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
        schemaLocation="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"/>
    <xs:import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
        schemaLocation="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>


    <!--    SOAP Header Elements -->  
    <xs:element name="ID">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:simpleContent>
                <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                    <xs:attribute ref="soapenv:mustUnderstand" use="required" fixed="1"/>
                </xs:extension>
            </xs:simpleContent>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="HoldRequests">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:simpleContent>
                <xs:extension base="xs:boolean">
                    <xs:attribute ref="soapenv:mustUnderstand" use="required" fixed="1"/>
                </xs:extension>
            </xs:simpleContent>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>  

    <!-- Type definitions -->    
    <xs:complexType name="DeviceIdStruct">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Manufacturer">
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                        <xs:maxLength value="64"/>
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="OUI">
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                        <xs:length value="6"/>
                        <xs:pattern value="[0-9A-F]{6}"/>
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="ProductClass">
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                        <xs:maxLength value="64"/>
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="SerialNumber">
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                        <xs:maxLength value="64"/>
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>


    <xs:complexType name="ParameterValueStruct">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Name">
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                        <xs:maxLength value="256"/>
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="Value" type="xs:anySimpleType"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="ParameterValueList">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:restriction base="soapenc:Array">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="ParameterValueStruct" type="tns:ParameterValueStruct" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                </xs:sequence>
                <xs:attribute ref="soapenc:arrayType" use="required"/>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:simpleType name="CommandKeyType">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:maxLength value="32"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <!--   messages  -->

    <!-- Send -->
    <xs:element name="Send">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>SendMessage </xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="DeviceId" type="tns:DeviceIdStruct"/>                
                <xs:element name="MaxEnvelopes" type="xs:unsignedInt"/>
                <xs:element name="CurrentTime" type="xs:dateTime"/>                
                <xs:element name="ParameterList" type="tns:ParameterValueList"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <!-- MessageResponse -->
    <xs:element name="MessageResponse">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>MessageResponse</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="MaxEnvelopes" type="xs:unsignedInt"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Thanks

Comment: I am somehow skeptical that generation classes for SOAP elements is a good idea. Could you please post the schema in question (or fragments thereof)?

Comment: Will try to do that. I don't know if it makes any difference but maybe I should have mentioned that the client is communicating RPC messages inside SOAP envelops.

Comment: Hi @lexicore. Sorry for the delay. I have found some time to generate a stripped-down version of the xml schema. Hope it helps.